# get a list item from a ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm interested in getting an **object reference** to a list item in a ListView when that item is clicked. Every item on my custom item XML contains a Button and a TextView that are `hidden` by default. The click on an item should change their `visibility` to `visible`.
Here's what I mean, done in the integrated graphic editor.

[image]

Should become this

[image]

This is my custom `getView` for the AdapterView

---

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup){

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater li= LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v= li.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
    }

    Student s= getItem(position);
    TextView name= v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    TextView surname= v.findViewById(R.id.txt_surname);
    TextView id= v.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);

    //following methods come from my Student class
    if(s != null){
        name.setText(s.getName());
        surname.setText(s.getSurname());
        id.setText(s.getId());
    }
    return v;
}
```

---

and here's what I (would like to) do in my Activity, but doesn't work by now.

---

```
ListView list= findViewById(R.id.advanced_list);
    final StudentAdapter adapter= new StudentAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_list_item,
            getStudents()
    );

    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView tel= findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
            Button delete= findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

            tel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show some code pls.

Comment: Read the documentation for `ListView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: You can check out my answer below on **how to change the visibility when your button is pressed** and also why it is that **your code is not working.** I've also given the link to a good tutorial in case you are still having difficulties with this. My answer has both a basic answer and elaborated answer, (the elaborated answer contains the code). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView tel= findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
        Button delete= findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        tel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

You're trying to look the `View`s up in the `Activity` layout, but they are in the `View` you get as the parameter. You can fix it like this:

```
...
TextView tel= view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);
Button delete= view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility in the listView row itself. I'd first like to state a problem I found in your code:

> TextView tel= findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);

it should be `TextView tel= view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tel);` since the TextView tel is not part of your main layout, but instead the listView's layout.
*Below are two explanations for how to handle the visibility.*

**Basic answer:**
In the `public View getView` method, just set an `onClickListener` or `onTouchListener` for whatever item you want to be clicked to make the others visible. 
To toggle the visibility of your TextViews, just do `textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and put this in the `onClickListener`. All of this code should be in your ListView Adapter.

**Elaborated answer:**
Here is the code

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {
     private Context mContext;
     Activity activity;
     private List<MyClass> class = new ArrayList<>();

     public LogAdapter(Activity a, Context context, ArrayList<MyClass> list) {
         super(context, 0, list);
         mContext = context;
         activity = a;
         class= list;
     }
     @NonNull
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
         View listItem = convertView;
         if (listItem == null){
             //If the row is empty, inflate it with your elements found in the 'mylistview' layout file.
             listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.mylistview, parent, false);
         }
         //These names and views are made up. You can change them to suit your needs for which items should become visible on a certain items click.
         Button changeVisibility = listItem.findViewById(R.id.change);
         TextView name = listItem.findViewById(R.id.name);
         TextView surname = listItem.findViewById(R.id.surname);

         changeVisibility.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(final View view) {
                 name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 surname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

The names, such as `MyAdapter` and the class `MyClass` are just examples, you need to make those. Once you do, your Adapter class should look like mine above. You can also change the button and TextView names, it just depends upon what layout file you are inflating your `listItem` with.

If you are still having problems with your code, check out [this link](https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd) for an explanation on how to make your custom listView from scratch.
Hope this helps!